# Desktop background updating by link

Tags: java, windows

I already have a link http://cam.sheratonamsterdamairportview.com/view_live1.jpg.
This link links to a camera at Schiphol Airport, that takes every 20 sec a picture.

I really want to get this photo every 20 sec updated as my desktopbackground. Is that possible?

Do I need to make a program or could i link it with a trick? I'm running Windows 7 btw.

Comment: For a full program solution look at the other answer, for a trick which will work perfectly well, require only a small program to update the image and just use the standard slideshow functionality for the background in windows then look at my answer.

Comment: @Jon Taylor -> what good is a random picture slideshow when Dave wants to have a constant updates from camera?

Comment: @mnmnc Im guessing you have not bothered to read my answer properly.  The random picture update is just so that windows updates the image.  There will in fact only ever be a single photo in the directory making it completely not random.  Everytime you poll from the server you overwrite the only photo in the directory.

Comment: Ok. my mistake then. But are you sure that overwriting the same file will cause windows slideshow to reload upon modification date change of the file? Isn't windows keeping the picture in the cache and loads it to the cache upon slideshow initialization? Do you think it will load the file each time it will 'randomly' choose it for the next picture? It might work - i'm just not sure if it will.

Comment: If that is the case than just give it a random string as its name.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows XP you can simply add active content on your desktop.

> Right Mouse Button on Desktop -> Properties -> Desktop tab ->
>   Customize Desktop -> Web tab -> New -> Location "www"

Setup your URL and activate content. You will have a small on-desktop window with the picture from camera. If it will not refresh automatically then create a simple page with meta refresh afver 20 seconds and img tag with src property setup for your link.

Im not sure if above works for Vista/7.

---

Otherwise

this will likely be useful to you:

```
'Set the wallpaper
 strComputer = "."
 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
 Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_VideoController",,48)
 Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Set WshSysEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   WinPath = WshSysEnv("SystemRoot") & "\YourWallpaper.bmp"

 If Not objFSO.FileExists(winpath) then
 'If the file does not exist then copy it
     For Each objItem in colItems 
         sourcePath = "\\path\here\"
         rightSize = "NameHere" & objItem.CurrentHorizontalResolution & "x" & objItem.CurrentVerticalResolution & ".bmp"
         objFSO.CopyFile sourcePath & rightSize, WSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings ("%SystemRoot%") & "\NameYourWallpaper.bmp", overwrite = True
     Next
 End If
 '************************************************************************************************************************************************
 'Set Wallpaper Bitmap to Default
 Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 sWinDir = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(0)
 sWallPaper = sWinDir & "\NameYourWallpaper.bmp"

 ' update in registry
 WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper", sWallPaper
 WshShell.Regwrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General\Wallpaper", sWallPaper
 WshShell.Regwrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General\BackupWallpaper", sWallPaper
 ' let the system know about the change
 WshShell.Run "%windir%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters", 1, True
```

This is VBscript that will change the desktop background and reload your profile afterwards to let you see the changes.

Or if you want something more here is a code you should take a look at:

This example demonstrates many useful techniques including:
Picking a file from a random list.
Setting the desktop wallpaper.
Setting the desktop wallpaper style (centered, tiled, or stretched).
Writing Registry entries.
Moving a file into the wastebasket.
Editing a file with the system's default editor.
When the program starts (and when you click the Apply button), the program calls ReadFiles. That routine reads the names of the files in the indicated directory and saves those that end in BMP, GIF, JPG, and JPEG. After it loads all the file names, the routine calls RandomizeNames to randomize the list.

```
Sub ReadFiles()
Dim file As String
Dim ext As String

    ' Create the new file name collection.
    Set FileNames = New Collection

    ' Get the file names.
    file = Dir(DirName & "\*.*")
    Do While file <> ""
        If LCase$(file) <> "temp.bmp" Then
            ext = UCase$(Right$(file, 4))
            If ext = ".BMP" Or ext = ".GIF" Or _
               ext = ".JPG" Or ext = "JPEG" _
               Then _
                    FileNames.Add file
        End If
        file = Dir()
    Loop

    NumNames = FileNames.Count
    RandomizeNames
End Sub
```

Subroutine RandomizeNames makes an array of indexes with one entry for each name in the FileNames collection. For i = 1 to NumNames - 1, the routine selects a random index and swaps it into position i.

```
Private Sub RandomizeNames()
Dim idx As Integer
Dim tmp As Integer
Dim i As Integer

    ReDim Indexes(1 To NumNames)
    For i = 1 To NumNames
        Indexes(i) = i
    Next i

    ' Randomize them.
    For i = 1 To NumNames - 1
        idx = Int((NumNames - i + 1) * Rnd + i)
        tmp = Indexes(i)
        Indexes(i) = Indexes(idx)
        Indexes(idx) = tmp
    Next i

    ' Point to the index to display.
    NextIndex = 1
End Sub
```

When a Timer fires, the program calls ShowFile to display the next file in the randomized list.

```
Private Sub SwitchTimer_Timer()
Dim secs As Long
Dim pic As Integer

    ' See if it's time yet.
    secs = DateDiff("s", Now, NextTime)
    If secs <= 1 Then
        If FileNames.Count > 1 Then
            pic = Indexes(NextIndex)
            NextIndex = NextIndex + 1
            If NextIndex > NumNames Then RandomizeNames

            ShowFile FileNames(pic)
        End If
        NextTime = DateAdd("s", Pause, Now)
        secs = Pause
    End If

    If secs <= 60 Then
        SwitchTimer.Interval = secs * 1000
    Else
        SwitchTimer.Interval = 60000
    End If
    SwitchTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Subroutine ShowFile checks the Style combo box and sets Registry entries to make the desktop image centered, tiled, or stretched.
Next, if the file is a bitmap file, the program simply calls the SystemParametersInfo API function to set the desktop background image.

If the file is not a bitmap file, the program loads it into a hidden PictureBox and then saves the image as a bitmap file. Then it calls SystemParametersInfo.

```
Private Sub ShowFile(ByVal file_name As String)
Const STYLE_CENTERED As String = "0"
Const STYLE_TILED As String = "1"
Const STYLE_STRETCHED As String = "2"
Const TILE_NO As String = "0"
Const TILE_YES As String = "1"

Dim had_error As Boolean

    ' Set the display style.
    had_error = False
    Select Case cboStyle.Text
        Case "Centered"
            If SetRegistryValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _
                "Control Panel\Desktop", "TileWallpaper", _
                    TILE_NO) _
                    Then had_error = True
            If SetRegistryValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _
                "Control Panel\Desktop", "WallpaperStyle", _
                    STYLE_CENTERED) _
                    Then had_error = True
        Case "Tiled"
            If SetRegistryValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _
                "Control Panel\Desktop", "TileWallpaper", _
                    TILE_YES) _
                    Then had_error = True
            If SetRegistryValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _
                "Control Panel\Desktop", "WallpaperStyle", _
                    STYLE_TILED) _
                    Then had_error = True
        Case "Stretched"
            If SetRegistryValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _
                "Control Panel\Desktop", "TileWallpaper", _
                    TILE_NO) _
                    Then had_error = True
            If SetRegistryValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _
                "Control Panel\Desktop", "WallpaperStyle", _
                    STYLE_STRETCHED) _
                    Then had_error = True
    End Select
    If had_error Then
        MsgBox "Error saving desktop style to registry.", _
            vbOKOnly, "Registry Error"
    End If

    ' Display the file.
    FileLabel.Caption = file_name
    m_CurrentFile = DirName & "\" & file_name
    If UCase$(Right$(file_name, 4)) = ".BMP" Then
        SystemParametersInfo SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, _
            0, m_CurrentFile, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE
    Else
        HiddenPict.Picture = LoadPicture(m_CurrentFile)
        SavePicture HiddenPict.Picture, DirName & _
            "\temp.bmp"
        SystemParametersInfo SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, _
            0, DirName & "\temp.bmp", _
            SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE
    End If
End Sub
```

When you click the Edit button, the program uses the ShellExecute API function to edit the current picture file.

```
Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
    ShellExecute ByVal 0&, "edit", m_CurrentFile, _
        vbNullString, vbNullString, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
End Sub
```

When you click the Delete button, the program calls subroutine DeleteFile to move the file into the wastebasket. It then displays the next picture.

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    ' Delete the file.
    DeleteFile m_CurrentFile, False

    ' Display the next file.
    cmdNext_Click
End Sub
```

Subroutine DeleteFile uses the SHFileOperation API function to move a file into the wastebasket, optionally asking the user to confirm.

```
Public Sub DeleteFile(ByVal file_name As String, ByVal _
    user_confirm As Boolean)
Dim op As SHFILEOPSTRUCT

    With op
        .wFunc = FO_DELETE
        .pFrom = file_name
        If user_confirm Then
            ' Make the user confirm.
            .fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO
        Else
            ' Do not make the user confirm.
            .fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO Or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION
        End If
    End With
    SHFileOperation op
End Sub
```

Taken from [here](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_backer.html)

Comment: I think this is pretty over the top for what he wanted to do.

Comment: you are probably right. ALthough i have updated my answer with VBscript solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well a rather simple way of doing it would be to create a program which overwrites a single photo in a directory.  Then get Windows (in the background settings) to make a slideshow and choose a random photo every 20 seconds from that directory.

Comment: OP wants a constant updates from camera so what good will be the random frame? after a month he will have a really really small chance to actually see the current picture.

Comment: why? This would work perfectly well and you would always have an updated photo, the most it's ever going to be out is 19 seconds and this will correct itself over time anyway.  The only way to avoid this is to poll more often or have some sort of callback from the server when the image is updated.  Since the server will not provide any form of callback, the only possible way to make sure its perfectly on time with any update is to poll more frequently.  Whether you use a full program to implement this or the way I have mentioned this poll frequency is going to be the deciding factor

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this, takes about 30 seconds to knock up a winforms application.
Not the best solution, but a quick and dirty starting point.

1) Make a folder e.g. `C:/wallpaper` and tell Windows to use a slideshow for your background using that folder.

2) A quick .NEt script to download the latest image

```
public bool running = true;
while(running){
string local= @"C:\wallpaper\localFile.jpg";
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://cam.sheratonamsterdamairportview.com/view_live1.jpg", 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);  //Wait 20 seconds.
}

}
```

Then have a button that makes running false when you want to quit. 
Windows will always look here and will change when the image changes - or should do if you have it using slideshow on that folder. (Slide show is a quick way of getting around the caching issue without loads of code) - Plus this will work even if you don't have admin rights to the machine.

Comment: Obviously not the best way to do it if this is for a project, but if it's just for personal use it should be ok. Caching *shouldnt* be an issue, but if it is, just save the last filename used, name the new one with a random number at the end using an iterator or something, then delete the old file.